# How to get the menu items in STS

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I accidently did somthing in my STS and now the menu item toolbar is missing(File,Edit etc Windows,Help) [image]

How to enable it back? I hope some one can help me,Please this is driving me crazy

Comment: It would be useful to know what exactly you "accidently did".

Comment: Actually i have something problem with my mouse.It shivers sometimes.When i clicked somewhere,it did some dragging function too.I didnt  see it properly my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is to reset the perspective. Right-click on the button corresponding to the current perspective in the upper-right hand corner on the screen (labelled "Resource" in your screenshot), select "Reset", then "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

Go to "window > new window", then it will open a new window with the top menu, then you can close the other window.